# Creating variable in loop linux - permission denied

Tags: linux, permissions, cut

I am trying to run this simple script in which I loop through a series of files in a directory and want to create a variable with 'cut', to extract part of the name of the files.
I get a permission denied error and cannot figure out why.
Below is my script.

```
FILES=./data/*

for f in $FILES
do
    NEWNAME=$($f|cut -c3-12)
    echo $NEWNAME
done
```

The ultimate goal is to create one directory per file for downstream processing, with `mkdir /path/to/new/directory/$NEWNAME`.

Comment: who's the owner and what's the permissions on the files in `./data/*` ?

Answer (score 4):

`$(stuff)` executes `stuff` as a command and substitutes its output back into the command line. So when you do:

```
$($f|cut -c3-12)
```

it tries to execute `$f` as a command, and pipes its output to `cut`. You get an error because the file in `$f` doesn't have execute permission.

If you're trying to cut the contents of the variable `$f`, you need to echo it:

```
NEWNAME=$(echo "$f" | cut -c3-12)
```

But there's no need to use `cut` for this, `bash` has a built-in parameter expansion operator to select a substring:

```
NEWNAME=${f:2:10}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked, and makes it clearer about the use of the syntax.